# Geodesic deviation using vector calculus for 2d surfaces in 3d space

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, vectors, geometry, geodesics

Is it even possible to derive geodesic deviation equation using vector calculus, I haven’t been able to find it in any textbook of classical differential geometry. I found a website with derivation of Riemann curvature tensor using vectors, http://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/5310/notes.htm

Comment: "Using vector calculus" should be more generally "using tensor calculus", since vector and vector fields can be interpreted as nothing more than tensor and tensor fields of order 1. Yesterday I came across a question from you, that has been treated like a homework and thus closed. I really appreciated the effort of writing tensor equations explicitly writing the base vectors, instead of relying on "strange" (at a first touch) definitions of covariant derivatives, and related mathematical objects.

Comment: If your question is equivalent to "can we derive  geodesic deviation equation, explicitly writing base vectors in tensor equations?", the answer should be equivalent to any valid derivation using tensor components. I wait for you reply, and then I'll start working on the derivation

Comment: @Shaashaank you probably won't find it in a differential geometry book because its more of a physics thing. maybe applied differential geometry.

Comment: @basics thank you for replying, yes, It actually wasn’t homework, I am doing it for myself. I just want to see the derivation done with base vectors (like the link I posted) written out and taking into account the normal vector as well(since the derivative of the unit normal vector also gives us a tangent vector). If you could help me out it would be great!